# Does Fey Ancestry still apply while polymorphed

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, racial-traits

My elf was polymorphed into a giant ape and had to make a Wisdom saving throw or else be charmed. I know that I make the saving throw with the giant ape's wisdom score but would the elf still get advantage?

The polymorph game text is, "The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality."

Verdict on if Fey Ancestry is a game statistics?

Comment: Related: "[What all is included in a creature's game statistics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138783)" and "[Can a polymorphed creature use class features that don't require speech or hand gestures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57717)" and "[Can I benefit from a feat effect while polymorphed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141776)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Your game statistics are replaced.

This includes your racial traits. Game statistics here refers to *everything mechanical about your character*. That is, all of your racial traits, class features, ability scores, everything.  We see this explained for NPCs in the *Monster Manual*:

> A monster’s statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster.

But this applies to PCs as well - your statistics are everything that make you, well, you, within the calculus of the game rules. In the *Player’s Handbook*, we have reference to game statistics in the step by step character creation section:

> Your character is a combination of *game statistics*, roleplaying hooks, and your imagination.

So your racial traits are “game statistics”, and are replaced when you *polymorph*. You’re a giant ape, not an elf, so you do not get advantage on the saving throw.