# If a dragon uses Change Shape to turn into an Evoker, does it gain/have the material components for its spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, spell-components, shapeshifting

Nuanced question about [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) (TP) and dragons changing shape:

I have a wizard who has a [*simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) (sim). Wizard TPs the sim into an [Adult Bronze Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-bronze-dragon), which can then Change Shape into a humanoid or beast of its CR or below. TP says the sim retains personality and alignment, so it still holds loyalty to me. I have it transform into, say, an [Evoker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/evoker) (CR 9 humanoid wizard with spellcasting prepared) from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*.

One of the Evoker's prepared spells is *stoneskin*, which requires a material component of 100gp's worth of diamond dust. **Does the dragon gain the Evoker's material components automatically upon transforming, or will I have to provide them some other way?**

Comment: Related: [Does the True Polymorph spell form a creature with equipment?](/questions/57124), [Can you obtain a Transmuter's Stone if you “morph” into a Transmuter statblock?](/questions/152743)

Comment: Please, limit yourself to one question per question. Also, see ones linked by MikeQ, parts of this are already answered, it seems.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of those, because those are about the *true polymorph* spell, not the dragon's Change Shape trait.

Comment: I attempted to edit the question down, but it didn't take apparently. The latter half is more important - I've seen no questions regarding material components when a true polymorphed creature interacts with Prepared Spells. Prepared Spells don't state that material components are provided, which begs the question of if they are implied/included in statblocks or not.

Comment: That...ok. That is /ungodly/. Would that same logic apply to a Ki-Rin, which has True Resurrection prepared (requiring a 25,000gp material component)?

Answer (score 3):

## Change Shape excludes the Spellcasting class feature

The last sentence of the [Adult Bronze Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-bronze-dragon)'s Change Shape reads (emphasis mine):

> Its statistics and capabilities are otherwise replaced by those of the new form, **except any class features** or legendary actions of that form.

Does Spellcasting count as a class feature? The [2018 D&D Basic Rules PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) says the following about monster special traits (p. 113; emphasis mine):

> ### Spellcasting
>
> A monster with the Spellcasting **class feature** has a spellcaster level and spell slots [...]
>
> The monster has a list of spells known or prepared from a particular **class**.

Therefore, a dragon using Change Shape to become an Evoker does not have access to the Evoker's Spellcasting.

### Rules sources disagree on "class feature" vs "special trait"

The latest digital sources agree that Spellcasting is a "class feature". The physical Monster Manual is a weird outlier, though. It went from "class feature" in the first printing, to "special trait" in the fifth printing*.

The [November 2018 Monster Manual Errata PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/MM-Errata.pdf) does not mention any changes, so the most likely scenario is that an error was introduced by the time of the fifth printing, due to copying from older digital sources (like the SRD).

Additionally, all sources include the line

> The monster has a list of spells known or prepared from a particular **class**.

...which indicates that Spellcasting is a class feature. Lastly, Jeremy Crawford states that [the Spellcasting trait in monsters is a class feature](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/29/the-spellcasting-trait-in-monsters-is-associated-with-a-class/). His tweets are [no longer considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140222/47185), but they can still provide insight into the intent behind certain rules.

What follows is a breakdown of which sources say "class feature" and which say "special trait":

#### Class Feature

> A monster with the Spellcasting **class feature** has a spellcaster level and spell slots [...]

- The [2018 D&D Basic Rules PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf)
- The first printing of the physical Monster Manual
- The [Monster Manual on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm)

#### Special Trait

> A monster with the Spellcasting **special trait** has a spellcaster level and spell slots [...]

- The [SRD](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=258) (last updated in 2016)
- The fifth printing of the physical Monster Manual
- The [Basic Rules on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules)

(Credit to [V2Blast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/33569/v2blast) for pointing out these differences in the comments.)

<sup>* (The fifth Monster Manual printing is denoted by "9 8 7 6" below "First Printing: September 2014" on the back side of the first page. The first printing would be "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2", the second printing would be "9 8 7 6 5 4 3", etc.)</sup>

---

## If Change Shape *didn't* exclude Spellcasting, you would form with the necessary components

The Monster Manual has an entire section titled "Statistics". In it, the last subheader reads (MM, p. 11):

> ### Equipment
>
> [...]
>
> If a spellcasting monster needs material components to cast its spells, assume that it has the material components it needs to cast the spells in its stat block.

Material components count as equipment, equipment counts as statistics, and Change Shape replaces the dragon's statistics, so the dragon would also form with any necessary material components.

(Credit to [Rubiksmoose's answer to "What all is included in a creature's game statistics?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138800/47185).)

Comment: The basic rules on D&D Beyond and the [SRD](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=258) (which hasn't been updated since 2016) both call it "the Spellcasting special trait". In contrast, the basic rules PDF, the first printing of the physical Monster Manual, and the Monster Manual on D&D Beyond all call it "the Spellcasting class feature". (Note that the D&D Beyond versions may just be inaccurate if the physical version changed, simply because the errata PDFs don't note the change.)

Comment: Also related: [a 2017 Twitter exchange with Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/29/the-spellcasting-trait-in-monsters-is-associated-with-a-class/) on whether Spellcasting is a class feature for monsters. Crawford explains: ["The Spellcasting trait in monsters is associated with a class, as explained in the introduction to the Monster Manual. That's a class feature."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928771874678435840)

Comment: Goodness, what a tangled ball of confusion.  Thanks for doing that research to shed some light on it.  +1