# Since pixies can cast polymorph, can a party chain polymorph to all become pixies?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, pixie

Pixies are CR1/4 so any character targeted with polymorph could become a pixie. Polymorph is an ability a pixie has that can be cast at 1/day. So if a wizard cast polymorph on themselves to a pixie I think they can then cast polymorph again on a party member to make them a pixie. That member could then do the same to the next party member etc.

Probably not the most effective use of polymorph for combat, but since pixies fly and are invisible seems like instant solve for most stealth missions.

Maybe one should rule that they wouldn't have the once per day available?

Comment: related: [Is the Conjure Woodland Beings spell (to summon pixies) broken?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159314/is-the-conjure-woodland-beings-spell-to-summon-pixies-broken), [Are pixies overpowered for CR 1/4?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203014/are-pixies-overpowered-for-cr-1-4)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This does not work. Plain *Polymorph* is limited to transformation into beasts (emphasis added):

> The new form can be any *beast* whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's (or the target's level, if it doesn't have a challenge rating).

Since Pixies are Fey, not Beasts, *Polymorph* can't transform you into a Pixie, and the higher level *True Polymorph* spell that *could* perform this transformation couldn't chain to produce more Pixies (because the Pixie itself only has plain *Polymorph*).

Comment: On top of that, it does not appear that *True Polymorph* would be in the statblock of *any* officially published creatures as of writing, outside of two named NPCs: Scanlan Shorthalt from *Tal'dorei campaign setting reborn* (3rd party published but available on D&D Beyond) and Arcturia from *Dungeon of the mad mage*, though the latter has a prohibitively high CR of 21. And obviously you'd have to convince your DM to allow you to polymorph into a specific NPC first...

Comment: @Kryomaani: Yeah, and while *True Polymorph* isn't quite as clear about it as *Shapechange*, I'd argue that "you turn a creature into another *kind* of creature" (emphasis added) indicates that you can't turn them into a specific (leveled) example of another kind of creature. It's already kinda ridiculous that, RAW, [you can turn someone into an archmage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153898/28941) (which is just a simplified pre-built high-level Wizard), but letting someone turn into a specific individual is definitely violating the "kind of creature" clause.