# How are magical effects on a creature copied/transferred when a spell copies/shapechange a creature by "removing" its equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

This becomes important when a spell such as Simulacrum or True Polymorph, or any other shapechanging spell that affects equipment, is cast.

Say I make a Simulacrum of an orc, let's call him Simulacr-Orc, that is armed with an axe and the orc has a Haste spell on it. The spell says that the copy won't have any equipment. So, no axe for Simulacr-Orc. But does Simulacr-Orc gets a Haste spell on itself?

And what about permanent magical effects instead? While the rules don't say much about ***how*** a permanent magical effect might exist on a creature, let's ***suppose*** that there is such an effect. Something happened to that orc in the past, we have no idea what, except that this orc now has a ***permanent*** Haste spell on it. The source of the magical effect, how exactly that happened, is not important here, only the magical effect, in the same way that when a delivery truck brings you a package, it is the nature and content of the package that is important, not the color or size of the delivery truck. So, will Simulacr-Orc also get the same permanent Haste magic on itself? Or a non-permanent Haste magic? Or no Haste magic whatsoever?

After all, creating a permanent magical Haste effect is pretty much like the equivalent of creating a magical item, like, say, some kinds of Boots of Haste. And with Simulacrum, items, magical or not, don't get copied over, right? Our orc's "permanent" Haste would be akin to the orc owning fully invisible, intangible, Boots of Haste, that he doesn't need to wear on his feet to use, that doesn't prevent other boots on his feets, and that also don't need to even be inside his equipment at all. Kind of like I'm here, and I own 1000$, but that 100$ ain't on me, it's in my bank account, and yet I still own it and can I still use it. So, yeah, permanent Haste on orc: will Simulacr-Orc get something or what?

What about some past event (whatever it is) that *magically modified* our orc, in an instantaneous way. Instantaneous is like how a Fireball is an instantaneous spell, that does it's damage, but then after the spell is fully gone, the damage remains and is still there. Similarly, that mysterious magical event came and modified the orc. Our orc instantaneously gained both a +2 ***bonus*** to Strength, and a +2 ***ability increase*** to Strength. So, would Simulacr-Orc also gain those benefits? Only one? And then, which one? Or none?

In short: Are magical effects copied over, and, if yes, which ones (aka "to what degree")?

Basically, anything in the RAW rules supporting either interpretation?

Thanks!

Comment: These may be considered separate questions, but they're pretty closely related and probably close enough. But I would be clearer as to the in-game rules you're using to determine the magical effect. I think *haste* is clear, but your *wish* or some other mechanic for granting the Ability score increase is not. Voting to close until clarified so we can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: It is the one exact same question. How are magical effects treated by Simulacrum and True Polymorph or any shapechanging power which affects equipment, and to what "level" is the magic affected. All? None? Something in between? I can rephrase the question if you think this is vital.

Comment: It's more that I don't understand your 'bigger' magical effect. Greater Demons don't have an ability to grant a *wish*, right?

Comment: That seems like a comment about the color the van that brought you a package, not on the package, maybe? It's really not really important what the source of the effect is. Wether greater demons can cast wish or not is another question entirely. Anyway I changed it to a deity to make it clearer.

Comment: It may just be me, but I prefer questions on either actual events or specific interactions. Raising an ability score is not one of the 'given' options for *wish* and thus may be subject to DM fiat. Keeping your question within known rules makes it more answerable. But if you really want it this way, we can just roll with the assumption that this non-standard *wish* was granted as-is.

Comment: Having said the above, is there a difference between your permanent magical effect (which needs an example if it is) vs the instantaneous *wish* example?

Comment: THe update made this more confusing to me. There is only *wish*. If you're homebrewing a spell or effect, you need to give us the details on it. If you want to use *wish* as your example, but just say the *wish* was successful without problems, that's okay, too.

Comment: Permanent is (almost always) dispellable (and often dismissable too). The few ones that aren't dispellable normally usually specify a unique way to get rid of the effect instead. Permanent is thus an "ongoing" magical effect without duration limnit. Meanwhile Instantaneous means the spell does its work and then the spell and its magic are fully gone aka you can't "dispel/dismiss" a Fireball's damage in later rounds.

Answer (score 5):

## In general, magical effects are neither part of statistics nor equipment and are not copied over to a simulacrum

Equipment doesn't have a formal definition in the rules, but it is clear from everything that the rules do call "equipment" that the term applies to objects. Magical effects are usually not objects (generally only when a spell creates an object) and thus generally would not go under equipment. Certainly, there is absolutely no way in which a spell like *haste* could be considered equipment.

Magical effects that don't explicitly change a creature's statistics don't count as statistics either. See [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/what-all-is-included-in-a-creatures-game-statistics?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.8495) for a detailed breakdown of what the rules define to be "statistics". Magical effects are not on there. *Haste*, for example, is a spell that gives several benefits. None of them  change a creature's statistics and thus don't apply to effects which copy statistics. Thus, when you copy a creature with magical effects that don't change statistics, the effects are not copied over to the simulacrum.

#### If an effect changes statistics, it is copied over

However, if a magical effect has changed a creature's statistics, then that would carry over since the simulacrum copies the creature's statistics exactly at the time the casting is completed with no exceptions made for magical or any other effects. Whether the effects are permanent or not don't matter. Your *wish* examples would fit here since they explicitly  change the statistics of the creature by changing their ability scores which are explicitly part of a creature's stat block.

It is unclear if you copy a temporary statistics change if it would still be temporary on the simulacrum or not, so that would be up to the DM to decide.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was an incredibly useful answer. I know how to rule it now: if a statistic (in the list you link to) is changed directly, then it is copied over. If it is some magical effect, not copied. But if the creature is not a copy but a changed form, like for True Polymorph, then all spells and magics remains "glued" to the new form.

Comment: @Pat I'm glad it is helpful! Yeah in the case of (True) polymorph things  get even more complicated because you also have to rule on if any conditional statements in spells (eg must target humanoid) still apply after it has been cast and the target has changed. Just another unclear area of the rules requiring a DM ruling.

Comment: More of a concern of *simulacrum*, but are you saying that the creature stats are only relevant upon completion? So that if you are casting the 12 hour *simulacrum*, but at the 11:59 someone casts *feeblemind* on your 'target', then the *simulacrum* now is stuck with those scores?

Comment: @NautArch I would say that would be the ruling that would make the most sense to me. The statistics of the creature up until the point of completion should have no effect on the finished product because the spell is only "cast" completely at one instant which is the last moment right? The same would be true in reverse, if the creature had some sort of negative temporary stat adjustment and it ran out and reverted during casting, that would not count towards the final product either.

Comment: @NautArch Then again, I guess one could make the case for the statistics at the beginning of casting only? That makes less sense to me and didn't even occur to me to consider honestly. Might be a good follow-up question to this though.