# Can a Changeling or Doppelgänger shapechange into a hybrid lycanthrope form?

Tags: dnd-5e, shapeshifting, lycanthropy, changeling

If a doppelgänger or changeling meet a werewolf in their hybrid form, could the doppelgänger/changeling then mimic that form?

Technically, a werewolf is a humanoid. But Shapechanger is an ability.

Answer (score 14):

#### You cannot change your statistics when shapechanging

The [Doppelganger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/doppelganger)'s Shapechanger trait states:

> [...] Its statistics, other than its size, are the same in each form. [...]

And the [Changeling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/changeling)'s Shapechanger trait states:

> [...] none of your game statistics change. [...]

We know "[What all is included in a creature's game statistics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138783)" which is basically everything about an NPC, monster, PC, or anything else really. And these features *cannot* change your statistics. So while you might be able to *look* like a hybrid form that you have seen, you would not gain any benefits that that creature usually has.

Comment: Good answer and I upvoted, but it buries the lede. I suggest leading with the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

[Doppelgangers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/doppelganger) can turn into into any Small or Medium humanoid they have seen and [Changelings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/changeling) can turn into any creature they have seen, if it has the same basic arrangement of limbs - which includes the werewolf hybrid form, since it is a creature with the same basic arrangement of limbs.

That said, their stats stay the same as in the normal form: this feature is designed for infiltration, you mimic neither their existing equipment, nor their traits and statblock.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.