# How many hit points can a druid generate per day from Aid with Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape, hit-points

Alice is a 2nd level druid with 10 hit points. She receives the benefit of an [Aid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aid) spell, bumping her to 15 max and current hit points.

She then has a run-in with a couple of goblins, who hurt her for five damage. She Wild Shapes into a [wolf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/wolf) which normally would have 11 hit points.

> The target assumes the hit points of its new form, and when it reverts to its normal form, it returns to the number of hit points it had before it transformed. (...) You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die.

The hit point maxium of the Aid [transfers to the wolf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196815/what-happens-when-the-aid-spell-ends-on-a-creature-while-its-hit-point-maximum-h). There are now two scenarios:

### Scenario 1:

**Current hit points are replaced by the normal hit points of the new form along with a higher hit point maximum.**

Alice-Wolf has 11 hit points. After the goblins beat her down to 0, she reverts to human form, suffers one more hit down to 5, transforms again into a wolf with 11 hits, get clobbered down to 0 again, and reverts to human form. Finally, she defeates the goblins.

She now must rest to regain some hit points, because when Aid will run out, [she'll lose 5 hit points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45342/if-the-aid-spell-has-been-cast-on-a-target-what-happens-to-their-current-hit-po).

In this scenario, she has produced no additional hit points from Aid beyond the 5 she originally received.

### Scenario 2:

**A new form receives both the enhanced maximum hit points and extra current hit points from Aid**

Alice-Wolf receives 5 hits points and now has 16 hit points. She fights the goblins and gets reduced to 0 hit points, reverts, and because the effect of adding current hit point applies to each new form, receives another 5 hit points up to 15.

Another hit reduces her to 10 hit point again, she employs her second use of Wild Shape, back to wolf form collects another 5 hit points. She is reduced to 0 points once more, reverts and receives another 5 points back up to 15. Finally, she defeats the goblins.

In this scenario, she has produced 20 additional hit points beyond those Aid originally provided. Alice can repeat this after each short rest, producing a possible 140 hit points from Aid over the course of a day (assuming the last hour is used fighting).

**How does Aid interact with Wild Shape? Scenario 1 or Scenario 2? Or yet another Scenario?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134882/discussion-between-nautarch-and-groody-the-hobgoblin).

Comment: Related Question: [What happens when the Aid spell ends on a creature while its hit point maximum has been changed to another value?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/196815/52137)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Alice's hit points and hit point maximum change, but that's it

Alice is targeted with *aid* and goes from 10 hp to 15 hp from the spell. After being hit, she now has 10 hp again.

She then Wild Shapes into a wolf... and has 11 hp, just like a normal wolf. Contrary to what [the other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/196821/38834) wrote.

Why? Because Alice is still the same target. Wild Shape doesn't change Alice into a new target; Alice is still Alice, just in a different form. Alice's hit point maximum was raised by 5 along with her hp. She then "assume[s] the shape of a beast".

The *aid* spell is still in effect on her. Her maximum did not decrease. And as the description goes: "...Your game statistics are **replaced** by the statistics of the beast...".

#### Sage Advice concurs

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=20) directly addresses the question of spell effects remaining after *polymorph*:

> **Can a creature under the effects of *polymorph* have other spell effects on them, or are those game statistics also replaced by the those of the beast form?** *Polymorph* replaces only the target’s character sheet or stat block with the stat block of the chosen form. Other effects, such as other spells, still exist.

### Hit points are part of the stat block; therefore replaced

Alice's hit point maximum statistic is 15; not 10 + 5.

It is replaced with the wolf's hit point maximum statistic, which is 11 (or 2d8+2).

*Aid* still exists, as do other spells. But *aid* effects the stat block which is replaced. *Invisibility*, *pass without trace*, *guidance* can all continue to work also; but they are not controlled by the stat block.

#### Let's look at it from another perspective

We will go on the premise that the *aid* spell is still active and follows the form.

Alice was hit again and has only 5 hp left. To escape, Alice Wild Shape's into a wolf and the *aid* benefits follow; that means Alice would lose her benefits. So Alice is now at max hp 10 again, but she would also lose the 5 hit points that were granted by *aid*. If that's the case, she now has 0 hp out of max 10, knocking her unconscious.

She has become trapped in true form until she receives some form of healing.

### In the end...

Assuming Alice survives the goblin attack, she can still be healed up to 15 until the *aid* spell ends. But her wolf form does not also gain the benefit of +5 each time she changes shape.

Comment: I do not see any way to make the argument that you can increase the HP/Max HP every round. If you're going to say you can make that argument and use that to support your answer, then please actually make it.

Comment: @NautArch I completely removed the whole argument of once vs continual. In the end, I don't think my answer required it

Comment: Even though *aid* is currently active with very clear spell effects, you disagree that the currently active form that doesn't have those effects shouldn't get those effects?

Comment: Does the ongoing magical effect from _aid_ differ from a magic item that adds +1 strength?  Does the beast form benefit from the magical item that affects the STR of the stat block?

Answer (score 1):

To formulate a concrete answer, the spell applies the following;

**For 8 hours, 'you' (if declared as target) have 5 extra health, both in terms of maximum health and current health.** When you wildshape, all your physical statistics and attributes your original shape had, will be remembered and "frozen", while your statistics adopt the physical attributes and statistics that are relevant to the beast you wildshape into. Psychological attributes (WIS, INT, CHA, proficiencies, languages, etc), as well as any current lingering spells or boosts (not coming from worn equipment, UNLESS the item says so), will remain in effect.

This means that;

- Yes, your beastshape will have 5 additional hitpoints to both start your wildshape in, so long the effect lasts.
- No, the game will keep remembering; "I had X out of 15 hitpoints", because the effect never disappears from you until it is dispelled or its duration runs out. If the aid spell was removed from you during your wildshape, your shape loses the +5 hitpoints it had, and so will the hp of your original shape. If that through some way lets your original shape end up below 0 hitpoints, you will be downed (unconcious and unstable) as soon as you transform back.