# Can Alter Self give you hands on extra limbs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

Can the **Change Appearance** option of *[alter self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alter-self)* be used to give a four-armed creature hands on those other arms?

> You transform your appearance...You can make yourself appear as a member of another race, though none of your statistics change... your basic shape stays the same

In particular I was considering the Simic Hybrid race from Ravnica which can have additional appendages, but not additional hands:

> You have two special appendages growing alongside with your arms. Choose whether they're both claws or tentacles.

Can *alter self* change these appendages into functional arms with hands, say by emulating a girallon (a four-armed ape)?

Answer (score 10):

### No, you functionally cannot

> You can make yourself appear as a member of another race, though **none of your statistics change**...

A creature's game statistics include [everything that is on the creature's stat block or character sheet](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/what-all-is-included-in-a-creatures-game-statistics), including its actions. If you had additional hands that were functional, they would enable additional actions, and alter your game statistics.

You however can make it look like you had additional hands on these extra arms, as long as your original body has extra appendages that you could disguise as arms.

Comment: Interesting approach to the question by using game statistics, that hadn't crossed my mind. +1.